# What does smiles become fixed mean?

Tags: vocabulary

> "It's odd, because he usually gives us a reason why we're not allowed to go somewhere –– the forest's full of dangerous beasts, everyone knows that. I do think he might have told us prefects, at least."
>
> "And now, before we go to bed, let us sing the school song!" cried Dumbledore. Harry noticed that the other teachers' **smiles had become rather fixed**.
>
> *-- Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone* by J.K. Rowling

What does *smiles become fixed* mean?

(1) They all are happy enough to keep their smiles.

(2) They become nervous after the headmaster’s notice, the third-floor corridor is out of bounds. For it suggests protecting philosopher’s stone, and it also means imminent attack for it from You-Know-Who.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From NOAD:

> **fixed** (*adjective*) (of a person's expression) held for a long time without changing, esp. to conceal other feelings : *a fixed smile*.

A similar expression sometimes used is *a forced smile*. A *fixed* or *forced* smile means you **look** carefree and happy, but you're **not** carefree and happy.

The way I would interpret the passage is that the other teachers aren't feeling true school spirit while they sing the song. There could be many reasons for this – resentment, worry, grief, to name a few – but the exact reason would have to be determined from further context.

Comment: The definitions in NOAD and online Oxford dictionary are almost identical!

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Yes, interesting coincidence. But only for that particular nuance, it seems. NOAD: **fixed** _influence the outcome of (something, esp. a race, contest, or election) by illegal or underhanded means_. Oxford: **fixed** _(of a sports contest) having the outcome dishonestly predetermined_. Peculiar for sure.

Comment: @J.R. I'd argue that there's a difference between a *forced smile* and a *fixed smile*. While they both imply insincerity, a *fixed smile* is unchanging as if it were drawn on someone's face (more permanent), whereas a *forced smile* may or may not quickly fade.

Comment: Being a big Harry Potter fan, I think it's probably because they're all embarassed of the school song which they were about to sing - understandable, it's frankly nonsense xD

Answer (score 2):

From [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fixed),

> **fixed**
>
> (of a person’s expression) held for a long time without changing, especially to conceal other feelings: *a fixed smile*

Obviously, when teachers' smiles had become rather fixed, the smiles had not come from teachers' happiness.

Perhaps you might not even need a dictionary to understand this figurative expression after all. I remember I was told once that, *"a joker face has a fixed smile"*.